# Write an abstract factory implementation by using the ASP.NET core DI container: how to manage object lifetime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns, dependency-injection, ioc-container

We are migrating a huge code base from .NET framework to .NET core. Unfortunately some of the code we are migrating suffers of design smells, but we can't freely break things during this phase and we need carefully plan changes over time.

One of the main problems is that our code relies on a great number of abstract factories which are known to be [a code smell](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2016/abstract-factories-are-a-code-smell/) (at least when abused). One related issue is that the Castle Windsor container is widely used in the existing code and we would like to avoid using it inside ASP.NET core, where we prefer sticking to the default built in DI container.

I'm trying to understand whether it is possible to rewrite some of our abstract factories implementation, currently based on the castle windsor container, by using the ASP.NET core DI container. Based on my understanding of the dependency injection, writing these kind of classes in the application's composition root is **not** an issue; put another way having a class of the composition root which depends on the DI container is **not** a way to introduce the [service locator](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) code smell.

Currently our interface definition of our abstract factory is a **leaky** one, because it exposes a `Release` method which is there only to adhere to the Castle Windsor's [register resolve release pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasepattern/). This is the current interface definition:

```
public interface ICommandHandlerFactory
{
  ICommandHandler CreateHandler(Type commandType);
  void Release(ICommandHandler handler);
}
```

The concrete implementation depends on the Castle Windsor container in order to resolve the command handlers and release them when the user is done:

```
public class WindsorCommandHandlerFactory
{
   private readonly IKernel _container;

   public WindsorCommandHandlerFactory(IKernel container)
   {
      _container = container;
   }

   public ICommandHandler CreateHandler(Type commandType)
   {
     // here we create the command handler type from the command type and then
     // we ask the container to resolve the command handler type
   }

   public void Release(ICommandHandler handler)
   {
     _container.ReleaseComponent(handler);
   }
}
```

My question is related with the object lifetime management. The point is that with the ASP.NET core DI container the lifetime management is not based on the `Release` method, instead it is based on the
concept of [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicescope?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0).

The best practice is basically creating a scope from the application root container, resolve dependencies from the scope's container, use the dependencies and finally disposing of the scope. When the scope is disposed the scoped and transient services resolved inside the scope are decommissioned and memory leaks are avoided.

This is the corresponding code:

```
public class Worker 
{
  private readonly IServiceProvider container;
  
  public Worker(IServiceProvider container)
  {
    _container = container;
  }

  public void DoStuff()
  {
    using(var scope = container.CreateScope())
    {
      var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IService>();
      service.Work();
    }
  }
}
```

In order to adhere to this design I should clearly simplify the abstract factory definition, by removing the leaky (and now no more useful) `Release` method:

```
public interface ICommandHandlerFactory
{
  ICommandHandler CreateHandler(Type commandType);
}
```

Given this interface definition, how can I cope with the creation and disposal of the container scopes ?

I **can't** simply do the following thing, because when the scope is disposed the resolved dependencies are decommissioned and so **the calling code can potentially have a reference to a disposed object**:

```
// this WON'T work due to the scope disposal when the service is returned
public class CommandHandlerFactory 
    {
      private readonly IServiceProvider container;
      
      public CommandHandlerFactory(IServiceProvider container)
      {
        _container = container;
      }
      
      public ICommandHandler CreateHandler(Type commandType)
      {
         using(var scope = container.CreateScope())
        {
          Type commandHandlerType = ... // build the command handler type starting from the command type
        
          var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(commandHandlerType);
          return service;
        }
      }
    }
```

Do you have any idea ?

### Update

After carefully reading [this article](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2016/abstract-factories-are-a-code-smell/) again I realized that the solution to this design issue is pretty obvious.

The whole point of the discussion are the intrinsic problems with the abstract factory design pattern, so the way to solve is probably **avoiding the abstract factory at all**.

The following code is pretty auto explanatory and shows a way to replace the abstract factory with another abstraction (called `ICommandDispatcher` in the example) which is basically an adapter used to call the right command handler for the command to be processed.

```
public interface ICommand 
  {
  }

  public interface ICommandHandler<T> where T : ICommand
  {
    void Handle(T command);
  }

  public interface ICommandDispatcher
  {
    void Dispatch(ICommand command);
  }

  public class CommandDispatcher : ICommandDispatcher
  {
    private readonly IServiceProvider _container;

    public CommandDispatcher(IServiceProvider container)
    {
      _container = container ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(container));
    }

    public void Dispatch(ICommand command)
    {
      if (command == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(command));

      var commandType = command.GetType();
      var commandHandlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(commandType);

      using (var scope = _container.CreateScope())
      {
        var commandHandler = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(commandHandlerType);
        ((dynamic)commandHandler).Handle((dynamic)command);
      }
    }
  }
```

Now all the code previously depending on `ICommandHandlerFactory` should depend on the new abstraction `ICommandDispatcher`. Just remember to define the class `CommandDispatcher` in the composition root of your application (the composition root is the only module of the code allowed to depend upon the IOC container).

Comment: I think migrating to .Net Core and moving away from Castle Windsor (and any other fixes) should probably be done in separate steps. Why complicate things when they are already complicated enough. Assuming Castle Windsor is available for .Net Standard/.Net Core

Comment: Don't. Do not do that. Migration is itself complicated enough.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, a factory takes over for the DI container. When you use a factory, the factory manages the lifetime(s) of the things it creates. You can use the DI container to manage the lifetime of the *factory*, but that's where it stops.

Your question is really too broad to reasonably answer without rewriting your code for you. However, essentially, the factory should implement `IDisposable`. It should new up the things it's responsible for and then dispose of them in the `Dispose` method implementation. From the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` side, you'd register the factory as a singleton (so that it can manage lifetimes within the entire scope of the application lifetime, since again, it's taking over the DI container's role at this point). Then, you can inject the factory wherever you need it, and use it to create what you need.

Comment: so you are basically saying that having an abstract factory which delegates the object creation to the ioc container is a non sense. That is, when you decide to delegate object creation to a factory you must handle both the object creation and the object lifetime with the factory itself.

Comment: Yes. That is literally the point of a factory. If you can get the instance out of the container, then you don't need a factory.

Comment: Take IHttpClientFactory as an example. That exists because it needs to internally manage HttpMessageHandler instances in a concurrent dictionary keyed by name/type. The DI container can't handle that. If you ask for an HttpMessageHandler, it's going to give you the same one each time